# Bubble Sort - Proof of average case runtime complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bubble-sort

So, I've been given this question in my homework and I tried to solve it for a few days, but I can't reach to any solution :(

Given the enhanced Bubble Sort algorithm, the average runtime is:
[image]

whereas the array contains only numbers between 1 to n, and all the numbers in the array are different from each other (the "permutation i" in the given formula is a single permutation of the numbers in the array, array indexed from 0 to n-1)

I need to prove that the average runtime in the formula is Big Omega of (n^2), and then conclude that it is also Big Theta of (n^2)

I also know that when the number 1 is in the k position (k is between 0 and n-1), the algorithm performs **at lesast** n*k operations

Comment: What is "enhanced" about Bubble Sort?

Comment: Usually, the worst case for bubble-sort is to have an already sorted array, but in the other order (i.e. descending if you're sorting ascending, ascending if you're sorting descending). It's how you get the maximum number of operations to do.

Comment: There is the basic bubble sort algorithm, and the enhanced one with the swap flag and the inner loop index is different

Comment: I know the worst case, but It doesn't help me here with the average case